# stretch embedded vimeo in vue.js fails

Tags: vue.js, vimeo

Im using the [vue-vimeo-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-vimeo-player) in vue.js for embedding vimeo video. I want to stretch the video over the full width of the screen and make it responsive but I cannot make it to stretch.

Here is a simple component in vue illustrating the problem. I can of course change the player-height and player-width props to change the size but I cannot make it 100% and responsive. I thought the vimeo class in my css should solve this but no luck.

Any hint would be very much apreciated!

```
<template>
  <vimeo-player
    class="vimeo"
    ref="player"
    :video-id="videoID"
    @ready="onReady"
    :autoplay="true"
    :player-height="320"
    :player-width="640"
    loop="1"
  ></vimeo-player>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      videoID: "224712377",
      options: {},
      playerReady: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onReady() {
      this.playerReady = true;
    },
    play() {
      this.$refs.player.play();
    },
    stop() {
      this.$refs.player.stop();
    }
  }
};
</script> 

<style lang="scss">
.vimeo {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  // max-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vue component is just a wrapper for the vimeo player.

Upon further investigation,
the `vue-vimeo-player` is requiring the `vimeo` player npm package.
[vue-vimeo-player](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player/blob/master/src/main.js#L107)

`@Vimeo/player` has an option for `responsive` which is set to false as default.
  [github/vimeo/player](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#embed-options)

which you can pass through `vue-vimeo-player` via the `options` prop

such that

```
<template>
    <vimeo-player
        class="vimeo"
        ref="player"
        :options="{ responsive: true }"
        :video-id="videoID"
        @ready="onReady"
        :autoplay="true"
        :player-height="320"
        :player-width="640"
        loop="1"
      ></vimeo-player>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.vimeo {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  // max-height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

#### note:

> You may still need to handle css widths/styling

Comment: thanks! This did it: " :options="{ responsive: true }"  " (and the npm package is installed :) )

Comment: feel free to upvote it as well if you're happy with the answer - thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
<vimeo-player :video-id="video_id" class="embed-container" :options {'responsive':true}"></vimeo-player>

<style>
  .embed-container {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
</style>
```

Ref: https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-vimeo-player/issues/15